# Python Regex Deciphering

Tags: regex, python-3.x

Someone at my company created a regex string that is working as intended but I want to do similar things in the future and don't understand the mechanics of it.

```
import re

config = """
interface Ethernet1/2
 description Management
 ip address 192.168.1.190 255.255.255.0
 ip pim sparse-dense-mode
!
interface Ethernet1/3
 description to-IntDMVPN
 ip address 10.0.0.93 255.255.255.252
 ip pim sparse-dense-mode
!
router eigrp 1
 network 172.16.0.0 0.0.0.255
 redistribute ospf 1 metric 1 1 1 1 1
!
"""

intf_obj_list = re.compile(r'^interface\s*(\S+)(.+?)(?:^\S+|\Z)', re.S|re.M).findall(config)

print(str(intf_obj_list))
```

I understand up to `^interface\s*(\S+)` which matches the router interfaces but adding the `(.+?)` also matches the `/n` on the first line of each interface config even though the dot is supposed to match any character but the newline.  Now `(?:^\S+|\Z)` adds matching of the body of the configuration under the interface and I don't understand that section at all.  From what I could find `?:` is another way to configure backreferencing which after a fair amount of googling, I'm still not clear on and I'm not sure what the `^\S+|\Z` within it are accomplishing.  Finally, the `re.S` I think allows it to continue to run through the body while encountering newlines and `re.M` allows it to run through multiple lines. If anyone can help me to break down what's happening here I would greatly appreciate it.  Thanks

Comment: I would recommend going over some tutorials to better grasp regex. A great source of learning is also [https://regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/HTml93/3). Just copy-paste the regex there and you will see a detailed explanation to the right

Comment: Yeah, the question might appear lazy but I've done quite a bit of research trying to figure this out including regex101.  From what i can tell regex101 doesn't allow you to put in the `re.S|re.M` and the output I get from what I can plug in there doesn't match what I get from running the program within Python. `(?:^\S+|\Z)` shows up as a non-capturing group as well.

Comment: Yes you can add flags. In the edge of the regex bar you can select them (there is even a little flag to indicate that). Use the actual link I put in my comment, I took the bother to put your regex there and match the flags